# MFC pass data from CViewTree to CFormView

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC application based on CView class.

I need to pass data between CViewTree to the main view

```
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication1Doc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // <-- the CViewTree  is here
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication1View)); // <-- the main view (CFormView) is here
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* - Don't jump feet first into MFC, without sufficient background in C++ and Windows API programming. These questions keep popping up, and all of them are essentially the same: How to pass data between instances at runtime. The core issue that needs to be addressed is, that the OP always fails to understand their application's runtime structure, mostly because MFC is complex.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own message then use `AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->SendMessage(MY_MESSAGE)`. 
Handle MY_MESSAGE in your CFormView (CMainView ??) and cast to your derived CFormView if necessary.

Comment: as I know, that will be good for catching the event. but what if I want both will use same collection of data. is it possible?

Comment: make the collection of data static and don't forget to synchronize read/write operations.

Comment: you should only synchronize if you are sharing data between two or more threads ... if you don't use multi-threading then no need for data sync.

Answer (score 0):

A general example - try it in a dummy project before 'butchering up' your main app.

1a) Put the data in your document class. Whenever the data is modified, call [UpdateAllViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y59b487w.aspx#cdocument__updateallviews).

1b) Add a special function to grab the document from anywhere
in your app.

```
// Data class
class Item : public CObject
{
    // your data here
};

class MyDocument : public CDocument
{
public:

    // Get the document from 'anywhere' for SDI projects
    // See:
    // http://asg.unige.ch/Past/fuentes/Mfc/HowTo_8.html
    // http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?473808-MFC-Doc-View-How-to-get-the-active-document-anywhere-in-my-application

    static MyDocument* GetDoc()
    {
        auto frame = (CFrameWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd);
        return (MyDocument*)frame->GetActiveDocument();
    }

    static const int HintItemAdded = 1;
    // Add other hint constants here

    // Data functions
    void AddItem(Item const& item)
    {
        m_items.Add(item);

        // Call this if you need it    
        SetModifiedFlag();

        // Notify views that data has changed (via CView::OnUpdate)
        UpdateAllViews(nullptr, HintItemAdded,
            &m_items[m_items.GetUpperBound()]);
    }

    // Functions for inserting, updating, getting, removing data, etc.

private:
    CArray<Item> m_items;  // data
};
```

2) Manipulate the data in command handlers using the document:

```
// This handler could be in the document, a view (use GetDocument to get
// doc), frame (use GetActiveDocument to get doc), etc. If outside of
// those, use your special 'anywhere' function

void SomeClass::OnAddItemCommandHandler()
{
   CAddItemDlg dlg; // dialog that allows user input
   if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
   {
      // use the 'anywhere' function
      auto doc = MyDocument::GetDoc();

      // use the user input to create new item and pass it to
      // the document
      doc->AddItem(dlg.GetNewItem());
   }
}
```

3) Make sure your view has an OnUpdate handler. This gets called by the
   CDocument::UpdateAllViews function.

```
class MyView : public CFormView
{
    void OnUpdate(CView* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject* pHint) override
    {
        CFormView::OnUpdate(pSender, lHint, pHint);

        // Just added a new item. pHint points to the new item
        if (lHint == MyDocument::HintItemAdded)    
        {
            auto newItem = (Item*)(pHint);

            // Add the new item to a list box
            m_listBox.AddString(newItem.GetText());
        }
   }

   CListBox m_listBox;
}
```